# Cloudfare redirect to Github Pages from the non-primary domain

Tags: redirect, https, ssl-certificate, github-pages, cloudflare

I have my Github Pages set up with a custom domain: mark.gg. This domain is set in the CNAME file in the repository. The Enforce HTTPS option is also on.

I use Cloudflare for DNS and for the mark.gg domain I have the four A records and one www subdomain CNAME record set to point to Github. Everything works fine if I access my site on www.mark.gg, mark.gg, http://mark.gg, https://www.mark.gg.

[image]

In the Crypto section of Cloudflare I have SSL set to Full, Always Use HTTPS set to On, Onion Routing set to On, and Opportunistic Encryption set to On.

I'm having issues getting order domains to redirect to mark.gg through Cloudflare. For example for my markcerqueira.com domain, my current DNS setup is:

[image]

The 1.2.3.4 is a dummy IP address. The key here is I have the traffic routing through Cloudflare so I can have it trigger a Forwarding URL Page Rule:

[image]

I used to have just one Page Rule that forwarded `*markcerqueira.com/*` to `https://www.mark.gg` and that didn't work so this image is just the most recent stab in the dark.

The Page Rule works as I see the address updated to mark.gg when I visit markcerqueira.com but I get an insecure connection error: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN.

[image]

At this point, unsure if I'm just missing some option or what I'm trying to do is impossible via just solely Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was rooted in the SSL setting available in the Crypto tab. I had SSL set to Flexible under the (very incorrect) assumption that Flexible SSL would be less error-prone compared to Full or Full (Strict). Flexible SSL forbids HTTPS at the origin which is what Enforce HTTPS via GitHub Pages enables. Turning the setting to Full or Full (Strict) clears up my redirect issue. For good measure here are all the Crypto settings I have configured for my redirecting domain that currently work without issue:

- SSL - Full (Strict)
- Always Use HTTPS - On
- Authenticated Origin Pulls - On
- Minimum TLS Version - TLS 1.0
- Opportunistic Encryption - On
- Onion Routing - On
- Automatic HTTPS Rewrites - On